# Yii 1 cdbcriteria how to pass param to the on clause in join

Tags: join, yii, model, relation

I need to pass param to the on in join

```
    $criteria       = new CDbCriteria;
            $criteria->join = "left join invoices v1 on t.id=v1.s_id and v1.year=:year";
           $criteria->params= array(':year'=>$category->year); //will not work
```

error Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of
tokens

or if it could be implemented in my model

```
public function relations()
    {
    return array(
              'invoices'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'invoices', '', 'on'=>'t.id=invoices.sid and v1.year=:year', 'joinType'=>'left JOIN', 'alias'=>'invoices' ), //how to pass param :year?
```

how to pass the param in the join in either case ?
Thank you

Comment: try `$criteria->condition = 'v1.year = :year';`

Comment: This will change the result I want the condition to be on join which will not remove the null records if there is no child row. here if there was no invoices for parent row it will be filtered out by v1.year if the record was null.

Comment: `$criteria->condition = 'v1.year = :year OR v1.s_id IS NULL';` this will prevent inner join like behavior.